# PHP image upload changes all db row images(or dosn't change anyone)

Tags: php, image

I'm getting problem. That my Upload(Insert) and Edit scripts changes all images, not only one I need. I don't understand why its like that, becouse it worked fine and in one moment it broke and changes all pictures. If I insert new post(title,id,image and more) it changes all other images too.

Don't know why. I found one bug, but don't know why its like that. Image Upload won't insert image name, but inserts "1" Here is image: [imgur.com/a/Q79ac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6WIr.jpg) Before it nicely stored image names..

This is my ViewParts.php(Main page):

```
    <?php
    require_once("../../System/class.partcatalogue.php");
    require_once("../../Style/header.php");

    $part = new PARTS();

    $target_dir = "../../Images/Parts/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename(isset($_FILES["UploadImage"]["name"]));

    if((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "forminsert")
    {       
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $manufacture = strip_tags($_POST['manufacture']);
    $category = strip_tags($_POST['category']);
    $code = strip_tags($_POST['code']);
    $info = strip_tags($_POST['info']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["UploadImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $image = $target_file;
    } else {
    }

    if($name=="")   {
        $error[] = "Please, insert name!";  
    }
    if($manufacture=="")    {
        $error[] = "Please, insert manufacture!";   
    }
    else if($category=="")  {
        $error[] = "Please, select category!";  
    }
    else if($code=="")  {
        $error[] = 'Please, insert code!';
    }
    else if($info=="")  {
        $error[] = 'Please, insert info!';
    }
    if($part->insertPart($image,$name,$manufacture,$category,$code,$info)){ 
                    $auth_user->redirect('ViewParts.php');
                }

    }

    if((isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : null) == "formedit")
    {
    $part_id = strip_tags($_POST['part_id']);
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $manufacture = strip_tags($_POST['manufacture']);
    $category = strip_tags($_POST['category']);
    $code = strip_tags($_POST['code']);
    $info = strip_tags($_POST['info']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["UploadImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $image = $target_file;
    } else {
    }

    if($name=="")   {
        $error[] = "Please, insert name!";  
    }
    if($manufacture=="")    {
        $error[] = "Please, insert manufacture!";   
    }
    else if($category=="")  {
        $error[] = "Please, select category!";  
    }
    else if($code=="")  {
        $error[] = 'Please, insert code!';
    }
    else if($info=="")  {
        $error[] = 'Please, insert info!';
    }
    if($part->editPart($part_id,$name,$manufacture,$category,$code,$info,$image)){  
                    $auth_user->redirect('ViewParts.php');
                }

    }

    if((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "delete")
    {
    $part_id = $_GET['part_id'];
    $part->deletePart($part_id);
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="../../Style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="../../Style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Style/style.css" type="text/css"  />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">

       <form method="post" id="login-form">

        <center><h2 class="form-signin-heading">PARTS</h2><hr /></center>

        <div id="error">
        <?php
            if(isset($error))
            {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?> !
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <?php $part->selectParts(); ?>
        <span id="check-e"></span>
        </div>

        <hr />

      </form>

      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>


    <hr />


    <?php 
        if((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "edit"){
        $part_id = $_GET['part_id'];    ?>
        <div class="container">


       <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="login-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ViewParts.php?action=formedit">

        <center><h2 class="form-signin-heading">EDIT PART</h2><hr /></center>

        <div id="error">
        <?php
            if(isset($error))
            {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?> !
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <?php $part->selectPartForEdit(); ?>
        <span id="check-e"></span>
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <center><button type="submit" name="btnedit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button></center>
        </div>

      </form> 

    </div>
        <?php } ?>


    <hr />

     <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="insert-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ViewParts.php?action=forminsert">

     <center><h3 class="form-signin-heading">ADD PART</h3><hr /></center>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type='file' name='UploadImage'>
        <span id="check-e"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
        <span id="check-e"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <select name="manufacture" class="form-control" id="manufacture"> <option value=''>Select Manufacture<?php $part->selectManufacture(); ?></option></select>
        <span id="check-e"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="info" placeholder="Info" required />
        <span id="check-e"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" placeholder="Code" required />
        <span id="check-e"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <select name="category" class="form-control" id="category"> <option value=''>Select Category<?php $part->selectCategory(); ?></option></select>
        <span id="check-e"></span>
        </div>

        <hr />

        <center><button type="submit" name="btninsert" class="btn btn-default">ADD</button></center>
    </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is how my class looks:

```
public function insertPart($image,$name,$manufacture,$category,$code,$info)
{
    try
    {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO partcatalogue(image,name,manufacture,category,code,info) VALUES(:image, :name, :manufacture, :category, :code, :info)");

        $stmt->bindparam(":image", $image);                             
        $stmt->bindparam(":name", $name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":manufacture", $manufacture);
        $stmt->bindparam(":category", $category);
        $stmt->bindparam(":code", $code);
        $stmt->bindparam(":info", $info);


        $stmt->execute();   

        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}
```

Problem in image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkpwH.png)

Comment: An `INSERT` statement won't update all of the other existing rows in the table.  What's actually being overwritten here?

Comment: @David Yes, it won't need to update, but it updates all pages. Don't know why. I found one bug, but don't know why its like that. Image Upload won't insert image name, but inserts "1" Here is image: http://imgur.com/a/Q79ac Before it nicely stored image names..

Comment: Well, if all of your images are being written to *the same file name* then, yes, they're all going to be the same image.  How do you build that file name?  When you debug, where are you getting that `"1"` value?

Comment: @David I got a stupid answer.. I don't really know how to debug it. I just try to find where is something wrong.

Comment: Problem must be somewhere here?! 
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename(isset($_FILES["UploadImage"]["name"]));

Comment: SIDE NOTE: Surely you should be validating your input BEFORE you move the image file to disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do here?

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename(isset($_FILES["UploadImage"]["name"]));
```

`isset()` returns a boolean response.  So your file name will over ever be "true" or "false" (or "1" or "0").  If you want to use the actual name value, get rid of the `isset()`:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["UploadImage"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Ohh. Yeah, now it works. I made it becouse if i got this "notice" and I wanted it to remove, online was written that with isset can hide this message: Notice: Undefined index: UploadImage in C:\xampp\htdocs\ACP\Parts\ViewParts.php on line 8

Comment: @crelix20: You can still use `isset()`, just do it before that line of code.  Check if the value is set in one operation, then use the value in another operation (if it's set).

Comment: Big thank you. :) I'm just newbie in programming and was trying to hide that message and didn't think that problem is there..

Comment: Maybe you can help me, i don't really understand that isset. How can no i hide this message?

Comment: @crelix20: `isset()`, as its name implies, checks if a value is set.  In this case you're checking if a file has been uploaded.  So you'd use `isset()` in an `if` statement to see if the file has been uploaded.  If it has, process the upload.  If it hasn't, don't process the upload.  Currently your code attempts to process the upload (copy the file) whether it's there or not.  If the file ever isn't there, you'll get that warning.  Because you can't copy a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, you'r a nice guy. Its something like i got here, right? if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["UploadImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $image = $target_file;
    } else {
    }

Comment: @crelix20: Well, that code is still assuming that the file was uploaded (that `$_FILES["UploadImage"]` is set).  If you want to check `isset($_FILES["UploadImage"])`, you'd want to do that *before* you try to copy the uploaded file.

Comment: Thank you one more time David, now I understood. And it works like I want.